# Node.js with external jQuery file

Tags: node.js

I'm having an issue utilizing an external jQuery file with node.  I have several functions that I need to run but it isn't working.  I created a simple function to test but the error message I keep getting is TypeError: Object # has no method 'alert_helloworld'.  Here are my two files:

example.js

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var templateparser = require('./templateparser.js');
var test = templateparser.alert_helloworld();
```

templateparser.js

```
function alert_helloworld(){
console.log("Hello World");
return false;
}
```

HELP!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the exports object in templateparser.js:

```
exports = exports || {};

exports.alert_helloworld = function(){
    console.log("Hello World");
    return false;
}
```

Take a look at the modules docs: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports.alert_helloworld = function alert_helloworld(){
    console.log("Hello World");
    return false;
};
```

It's important you actually export the functions you need. node.js modules by default are wrapped in their own isolated module scope.

Comment: I'm not looking to reinvent my external file.  I want to keep it the same.  Is this even possible?

Comment: @user1146581 yes/no. You can inject it as a javascript file into jsdom or you can put it through an AST parser in node. Otherwise no, you can't access "global" variables that you define in your file.

Comment: So I guess I'm asking, how do I inject it as javascript into jsdom?